# Product specifications add

Tags: custom-options, addtocart

I just install magento. When I try to product add there already have many input field.

I need some multiple extra field that's can be some time one entry some time multiple entry

like

- extra option one
- extra option tow
- extra option three
- add more+

It is possible to magento?

**UPDATE**

Admin when need any product entry then he needs some product feature of specifications add. There have some attribute sets but that's are fixed.
Example: when admin add a new product a *android mobile*. It's specifications need OS, Battery, Ram, etc. That's I can add attribute sets. But I don't want to add attribute sets I need there are some free text input box(one or two) under specification label and a add more button when i click add more button then add one more text input box under specification label. After product entry from admin product front end show like this

- 3900 mAH Battery
- Android v5.0 (Lollipop) OS
- 3GB RAM
- 21 MP Primary Camera
- Front & Back Camera

There can be one specification or multiple specification depends on product.

Comment: what you mean by product add ,are you  taking about product cart or product attribute.? If you talk  about attribute need to create multi select product attribute at admin >catalog >manage attributes

Comment: Multi select are predefined but I need free input box there each product input can be different

Comment: Please clarify: Who should see the inputs? The admin or the customer? An example would help to understand what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello frinds you will create **attribute for specification**

**adminpanel->catelog->manageattributes**

and another thing try this code:-
 you create a new attribute for each item in the specification the Magento's default theme will show this as additional info in a nice table. Depending on your theme you could edit the table to display as you wish.

The benefit of doing your specification this way allows your products to be compared on each of the specification name:value pairs.

If none of that is an option then you can create one attribute called specification with an attribute code of spec_table and set the type as text area allowing you to enter the HTML you supplied. With this attribute set you can check for the field and output in your **product/view.phtml** file like so:

```
   `if($specTable = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('spec_table')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)) { echo $specTable }'
```